# How to passthrough a device to a podman container?

Tags: container, podman

I am running Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS and I am trying to use Podman.

I fail to passthrough a device (in my case /dev/ttyUSB0) to the container.

Running

```
podman --device /dev/ttyUSB0 ...
```

just does not have any effect, the device isn't there inside the container.

I also disabled AppArmor just to find out if this is causing my problem, yet no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your syntax is wrong. It should be like this: (notice the `=` between the option and the device)

```
podman run --device=host-device[:container-device][:permissions] ...
```

In your case that would be:

```
podman run --device=/dev/ttyUSB0 ...
```

Also please note that the `--device` option should be part of the `run` command when you start the container.

See the [reference manual](https://docs.podman.io/en/stable/markdown/podman-run.1.html#device-host-device-container-device-permissions) for more info on this.

Comment: Sorry, of course I used the --device together with the run command. And I have seen both --device /dev/xyz as well as --device=/dev/xyz in verious tutorials. Both doesnÄ work.

Comment: It turns out the problem appears when I start the container with --privileged